# Throwing "FormatException: Illegal scheme character" when using 'from.createSignedUrls()' on Image widget

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to display multiple images from supabase bucket on my flutter app screen but when I try passing each signed url from the list, I get a FormatException

Here is my FutureBuilder code

```
Future<List?> getURLs() async {
final List<FileObject> path = await Supabase.instance.client.storage
    .from("public-image")
    .list(path: user!.id);
final List<String> fpath =
    path.map((e) => '${user!.id}/${e.name}').toList();
final signedUrls = await Supabase.instance.client.storage
    .from("public-image")
    .createSignedUrls(fpath, 120);
return signedUrls;
}
```

- 

```
urls = DatabaseService().getURLs();
```

- 

```
FutureBuilder<List?>(
              future: urls,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasError && snapshot.hasData) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 500,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Card(
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            child: Image.network(
                              '${snapshot.data![index]}',
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            elevation: 5,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text('error');
                }
              })
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what the value of `snapshot.data![index]` is?

Comment: Yes! the value is : SignedUrl(path: 96649509-71a7-4ecf-82cf-9e22b6131558/image1.jpg, signedUrl: /object/sign/public-image/96649509-71a7-4ecf-82cf-9e22b6131558/image1.jpg?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1cmwiOiJwdWJsaWMtaW1hZ2UvOTY2NDk1MDktNzFhNy00ZWNmLTgyY2YtOWUyMmI2MTMxNTU4L2ltYWdlMS5qcGciLCJpYXQiOjE2NjgwNjMxNzksImV4cCI6MTY2ODA2MzI5OX0.vitDJrglPYhbRSpJ2VCV_wCbqMa4eRD23JpcdjRHRDU)

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `signedUrl` parameter to access the URL of the image. You can update the Image widget like this.

```dart
Image.network(
  snapshot.data![index].signedUrl,
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
```

For some cleanups, you can change the return type of getUrls to `List<SignedUrl>` like this:

```dart
Future<List<SignedUrl>> getURLs()
```

And update the type of your `FutureBuilder` as well:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<SignedUrl>>(
```